# The right side data appears in a row where left side data is ending

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, dynamic, grid

[image]

I want to accomplish how it's given in design. The right side data appears in a row where left side data is ending.

**My code**

```
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 ">
                        <p class="key text-capitalize  ">Decision [Is Equal To]   </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 ">
                        <p class="value text-capitalize "><span>: </span>  On Hold Temporarily 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Is there any way where we can do this dynamically using css?

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML because semantically this looks like tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML table to achieve this

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Label 1</td><td>: value</td></tr>

  <tr><td>Label Label 2</td><td>: value 1</td></tr>

  <tr><td>Label 3</td><td>: value value value</td></tr>
</table>
```